# The type 'X' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Y'

Tags: silverlight

My Silverlight 2 project is referencing DLL which has class that inherits System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.

I am getting an error: The type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Windows.Controls.Data'.

I have already added reference to System.Windows.Controls.Data into my project.

Any idea what might be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGrid` does not seem to be supported in Silverlight 2.

The **Version Information** section on the [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.95).aspx) page on MSDN says:

> **Silverlight**
>
> Supported in: 5, 4, 3